# Still the problem of debug project with GDB tool

Tags: debugging, gdb

Here is more specific explanation of what I want to make clear:

- I have some source c files locate
  under **JM/lencod/src** ;
- and some header h files locate under
  **JM/lencod/inc** ;
- and a *Makefile* locates at
  **JM/lencod** ;

After I compile these source files using *Makefile*, some of obj files will be generated under **JM/lencod/obj** , meanwhile a lencod.exe executable file is generated in **JM/bin**.

Then I want to debug it like what I can do using MS Visual Studio, i.e. step by step debug, watch the parameters changing...

How can I make that happen? To do like this??

```
$cd ~/JM/bin
$gdb lencod.exe
$break ****
$run
```

......
There is still one thing,i,e. if I want to set a breakpoint at the main function which is in one c source file lencod.c under JM/lencod/src. How to do this?

Simply typing:

```
$b main
```

?

Thanks very much for any possible help:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in order to set a breakpoint on entry in main you have to execute command:

> b main

Comment: No need to specify break in which file? 

After I set it "b main", I get the following info: """(gdb) b main Breakpoint 1 at 0x807a9f3""" which does not show to break in which file and also corresponding line number. Is it right?? I just doubt it.